# Regex - Matching characters then capturing

Tags: regex, powershell

this is my first post on StackOverflow, and regex is new to me, please bear with me.

I am attempting to capture fields within a powershell command event log.
I have text in the following format:

```
(Get-AdUser): name="Identity"; value="Username"
```

I want to capture the string inside the parenthesis *Get-ADUser* and also capture the value field of "username"

If possible a final output of

```
Get-AdUser Username
```

would be perfect.

The gotcha is that I want to capture any value inside the parenthesis except for the word "Out-Default". Out-Default is the output of a command, rather than the command itself.

So far I have:

```
\((?!Out-Default)([^)]+)\)
```

which is matching anything inside the parenthesis except "Out-Default".

I'm not sure how to approach it from here. Any advice is appreciated.

## Update - is it possible to use only 1 capture group to capture:

```
(Get-AdUser): name="Identity"; value="Username"
```

and have the result look like

```
Get-AdUser name=Identity value=Username
```

?

Comment: How about \((?!Out-Default)([^)]+)\).*;\s+(\w+)(?=\=\"Username\")

Answer (score 2):

Hope this work

```
\((?!Out-Default)([^)]+)\).*?value="([^"]+)"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xC3aT5/1)

**Explanation:**
`\`: Escapes a special character [sample](https://regex101.com/r/aM5iM5/1)
`( … )`: Capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qL1pP8/1)
`(?!…)`: Negative lookahead [sample](https://regex101.com/r/bI9fA5/1)
`[^x]`: One character that is not x [sample](https://regex101.com/r/bB0vG6/1)
`+`: One or more [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wV7cV2/1)
`.`: Any character except line break [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wY6xS4/1)
`*`: Zero or more times [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wE3zV2/1)
`?`: Once or none [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qX9nZ9/1)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. It works if all characters are on the same line. But how about the scenario where value="username" is on a separate line?